# Non parameteric tests for 2*2 mixed design

Tags: nonparametric, ordinal-data, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, bonferroni, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I have 2*2 mixed design, where the two factors are *time* and *group*. The *time* levels are *pre-* and *post-intervention*, and the *group* levels are *control* and *intervention*.

If I were using a parameteric test, I think a mixed ANOVA would be appropriate, but as the data is ordinal, I thought a non-parametric test would be more suitable.

Am I right in thinking that there isn't a non-parametric equivalent of a mixed ANOVA? Is using a Wilcoxon Signed Ranks test (for a within-subjects comparison of the *pre* and *post*) in conjunction with a Mann-Whitney U test (for a between-subjects comparison of the *control* and *intervention*) an appropriate substitute? If so, would I use Bonferonni's correction when looking at the p-levels (because I'm running two tests)?

Comment: So you have N cases, each measured twice (pre and post) on some ordinal measure (the DV) and each from one of two groups?

Comment: That's right. The intervention group (N=18) and the control group (N=20) were both measured at T1 (pre) and T2 (post). The DV is an ordinal measure.

Comment: There are more fancy solutions (and a not-negligible literature on the pros and cons of the strategy I am about to suggest) but wouldn't a simple analysis of difference score do the trick? You first subtract pre-intervention levels from post-intervention levels and analyze the resulting change score, with Mann-Whitney U test if you want.

Comment: In any case, an important thing to keep in mind is that the relevant analysis is not a simple function of the level of measurement of your variables. The most important question is “What do you hope to learn from this experiment?”

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I thought an analysis of variance would operate on the means and therefore wouldn't be appropriate for ordinal data? Or are there other analysis of variance tests? Beyond being ordinal, the data isn't meeting some of the other assumptions made by parametric tests (I've actually got multiple sets of data - some don't meet normality, some don't have homogeniety of variance).